# Jquery draggable ui with with multiple elements that revert back to original position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have setup a draggable ui and setup multiple elements to be given the same class on click. I can then drag a group of elements at once.

The problem I'm having is if I want to use the revert option, only one element will go back to its original position. I'm trying to prevent any elements from overlapping on mouse release when moving a group of divs all at once. Here is the code right now.

Here is the codepen to help:
https://codepen.io/5kyt3k/pen/JjjNBEV

```
var selectedClass = "ui-selected";


function dragTiles(){

  $( ".draggable" ).off('mouseup').on('mouseup', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging')){
      $(this).addClass(selectedClass);
    }else {
      $(this).toggleClass(selectedClass);
    }
  });

  $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
    snap: true,
    //grid: [ 1, 31 ],
    zIndex: 100,
    revert : "valid",

    start: function(e,ui){
      $(this).addClass(selectedClass);
      $(this).removeClass('prevent');
      var pz = $("#canvas");
      //we need current scale factor to adjust coordinates of dragging element
      currentScale = pz.panzoom("getMatrix")[0];
      $(this).css("cursor","move");
      pz.panzoom("disable");//disable panzoom to avoid double offset

      ui.position.left = ui.position.left/currentScale;
      ui.position.top = ui.position.top/currentScale;


      //drag multiple divs start
      if ($(this).hasClass("ui-selected")) {
           // if this is selected, attach current offset
           // of each selected element to that element
           selected = $(".ui-selected").each(function() {
               var el = $(this);
               el.data("offset", el.offset());
           });
       } else {
           // if this is not selected, clear current selection
           selected = $([]);
           $( "#canvas > div" ).removeClass("ui-selected");
       }
       offset = $(this).offset();
       //drag multiple divs end

    },
    drag:function(e,ui){
      //fix scale issue
      ui.position.left = ui.position.left/currentScale;
      ui.position.top = ui.position.top/currentScale;

      //drag multiple divs start
      var dt = ui.position.top - offset.top/currentScale, dl = ui.position.left - offset.left/currentScale;
      selected.not(this).each(function() {
         var $this = $(this);
         var elOffset = $this.data("offset");
         $this.css({top: elOffset.top/currentScale + dt, left: elOffset.left/currentScale + dl});
      });
      //drag multiple divs end

    },
    stop: function(e,ui){
      $(this).addClass('prevent');
      $(this).css("cursor","");
      //enable panzoom back
      $("#canvas").panzoom("enable");
    }
  })
   $(".tile-overlay").droppable({
     accept: '.draggable',
   });
};
```

Comment: Would be easier for someone willing to help you to also have some **minimal** HTML, CSS I think

Comment: PS: I remember once back in the days I needed something similar, and I was not able to make it work using plain jQuery Selectable/Draggable - SO I made my own from scratch.

Comment: I can setup up a function within Revert to get each position of the the elements I'm dragging.  Then change the css for each element with a specific class name. I'm just not sure how to get the original  positions (before dragging). I can get it during a function within Start....but can't pass it to Revert (at least I'm not sure how)